# How to order stacked bar chart in descending order?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

This is my data frame after group by *State* and *Category*. I was trying to create a descending stacked bar chart by the total *Number of Records* (combining all three categories) of each state. I tried to **sort_values** before plot as there is a 'Total by State' column. Unfortunately, i haven't been able to work out a way to sort this properly. 
[image]

i have tried some combo, but kinda in that frustrating phase now.. feel like i might be over-complex this though.

```
my_df_sort = my_df.groupby(['State','Category']).sum().sort_values(by=['State','Number of Records'])
my_df_sort2= my_df.groupby(['State']).sum().sort_values(by=['Number of Records'], ascending=False)
```

my desired outcome would be this data frame in the same format, just with the State column sorted by the total Number of Records in descending order. For example, California would appear in the first position as Technology:359 + Furniture :444 +Office Supplies: 1198 = 2001 is the largest.

(the current/unsorted stacked bar chart looked like this: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find the order of the states by calculating the sum for each state and grabbing the index from that. Use this order to reindex your dataframe and then plot. Something like this:

```
# Create sample data
np.random.seed(0)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['WA', 'NC', 'NY', 'ME', 'NE', 'SD', 'CA'], ['Furniture', 'Technology', 'Office Supplies']], names=['State', 'Category'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(21), index=index, columns=['value'])

# Find order and plot
sort_ix = df.groupby(level='State').sum().sort_values('value', ascending=False).index
df.reindex(sort_ix, level=0).unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]